# Using Array in Z3PY

Tags: arrays, z3, z3py, theorem-proving

I am using z3 for my research and I have the following problem. I am analyzing the model of a satisfiable formula that contains arrays, but I don't understand the results of model. For exemplo, I have two variables 'pkgcounter' and 'rxlen', and two propositions p1 and p2. My goal is to find out if there is a model that satisfy both propositions.

```
 pkgcounter = Array('pkgcounter',IntSort(),BitVecSort(8))

 rxlen = Array('rxlen',IntSort(),BitVecSort(8))

 s = Solver()

 p1 = (pkgcounter < rxlen)

 p2 = (pkgcounter == rxlen)


 s.add(p1,p2)

 if s.check() == sat:

    print s.model()
```

The result is the following model: 
    [rxlen = [else -> 0],
     pkgcounter = [else -> 0],
     k!0 = [else -> 0]]

Could anyone help me to interpret this result? Because if rxlen and pkgcounter have all fields equal to zero, the proposition p1 have no model.

Answer (score 3):

Depending of the versions of Z3 and Python you use, this problem will produce different results, all of them triggered by

```
p1 = (pkgcounter < rxlen)
```

In Python 2.7 `(pkgcounter < rxlen)` simplifies to `False`, because `ArrayRef` objects don't have a `<` operator and the objects are different. Conversely, Python 3.5 complains about these objects not being ordered (`TypeError: unorderable types: ArrayRef() < ArrayRef()`).

Note that Arrays in Z3 do not have a size; if they are indexed by integers, they are indeed of infinite size. So, `(pkgcounter < rxlen)` doesn't make sense in this context as those arrays can't be compared in this way. (See also [SMT ArraysEx Theory](http://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu/theories-ArraysEx.shtml)).

The reason for this testcase being satisfiable is probably that an old version of Z3 was used. In the latest version (master branch on GitHub) this is unsatisfiable, but again, that's because `p1` is `False`.

In general, models for Array variables are reported as function definitions, for instance `rxlen = [else -> 0]` means that the function to look up an element in the array `rxlen` is the function that always returns `0`. By adding

```
p3 = (rxlen[0] == 1)
```

We can force rxlen to have a different value in the first position and the model will then be reported as `rxlen = [0 -> 1, else -> 1]`; i.e., `1` in position `0` and `1` everywhere else.